# What is this bloated crack on my living room wall?

Tags: walls, crack

I just noticed this bloated and cracked surface in my living room in my rental apartment this morning. It was not there yesterday. It feels a bit moist and cracks easily. I've put a cloth duct tape covering to prevent anything harmful from entering my apartment through this crack. But what is it? And what could have caused this? Any suggestions/replies are appreciated

[image]

Comment: we have no idea since you didn't post a pic.   You are renting, call the management company. They are responsible for maintenance and repairs.

Comment: Dry cracks are common in drywall, but being moist is a problem.  There might be a plumbing leak or a roof leak if raining.  With the picture, call maintenance now.

Comment: I had trouble posting a photo. Just successfully posted it now

Comment: It looks like it pushed out quite a bit more than a normal crack, almost if someone hit it from the other side with a 2x4.  Can you measure the difference in height of the flat wall and the crack?  It looks like about an inch difference.

Comment: Definitely call maintenance _now_. It's their responsibility to fix it, whatever the cause. It definitely looks like an impact from the other side, but it could be that there's a pipe or roof leak, but in any case, it's all on them to take care of it. It's highly unlikely that anything harmful will come through, unless you're not on good terms with your neighbor.

Comment: Before I saw the picture, I assumed a moisture bubble, which would have a smooth curved surface, whereas your damaged surface has facets and a ridgeline, so I'd agree with crip659 and FreeMan that it looks like a couple of bashes from the other side.

Comment: Did your next door neighbors have a wild party last night? If not, it's something else coming through the wall and pieces of tape won't really stop something that bashes holes in drywall. It's time to call the maintenance guys. The beauty of renting is that neither problem is your responsibility to deal with.

Comment: Contact your landlord. It's their problem, being a rental.